# How to parse UNIX timestamps with luxon?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, luxon

I tried to use the `luxon` library to move away from `moment` - to translate the `1615065599.426264` timestamp into an ISO date.

According to the [Online Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) this corresponds to

> GMT: Saturday, March 6, 2021 9:19:59.426 PM
> Your time zone: Saturday, March 6, 2021 10:19:59.426 PM GMT+01:00
> Relative: 3 days ago

Removing the decimal part gives the same result.

The code using `luxon`:

```js
let timestamp = 1615065599.426264
console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromMillis(Math.trunc(timestamp)).toISO())
console.log(luxon.DateTime.fromMillis(timestamp).toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

This result is

```
1970-01-19T17:37:45.599+01:00
1970-01-19T17:37:45.599+01:00
```

It is suspiciously close to [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your timestamp seems to be seconds, not milliseconds, if you multiply the timestamp by 1000, you will get the expected date back when parsing.

Comment: @m90: pfff, I must have looked at it too long to not spot the obvious error :) - thanks a lot. Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: So use `luxon.DateTime.fromSeconds(timestamp)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to give a more complete answer, there are indeed 2 ways of storing timestamps: Seconds and milliseconds precisions.

JavaScript indeed uses ms precision by default.

Luxon provides 2 different methods:

- `DateTime.fromMillis(1691760353000)`
- `DateTime.fromSeconds(1691760353)`

Both will produce the same output when calling `date.toISO()`:

- `2023-08-11T13:25:53.000+00:00`

Depending on which precision you use, you need to use one or the other.

*I wrote this answer because the other answer didn't make that crystal clear, and I found myself using `toSeconds` when what I really wanted was `toMillis`.*

Answer (score 20):

Luxon can accept UNIX / epoch times in seconds with the .fromSeconds() function. You can then use the .toISO() function to output an ISO format.

in your specific example:

```
const { DateTime } = require('luxon')

//your other code here 

const myDateTime = DateTime.fromSeconds(1615065599.426264)
const myDateTimeISO = myDateTime.toISO()

//outputs '2021-03-07T08:19:59.426+11:00'
```

ref: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=unix-timestamps

Comment: Maybe later, but definitely a better answer since it uses a native function :).

Comment: Since unix/epoch timestamps are the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, you'll probably want to specify the UTC time zone when calling fromSeconds: `const myDateTime = DateTime.fromSeconds(1615065599.426264, { zone: "utc" })`. Otherwise, it will default to the time zone the code is running in. If you then want to convert that UTC time to another time zone (e,.g., Pacific), do something like: `const pacificDateTime = myDateTime.setZone("America/Los_Angeles")`

Answer (score 9):

So called ["Unix time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) counts the number of **seconds** since 01.01.1970 whereas Luxon (and most things JavaScript) expects a value with a **millisecond** resolution.

Multiplying your value by 1000 will yield the expected result:

```
> let timestamp = 1615065599.426264
undefined
> new Date(timestamp).toJSON()
'1970-01-19T16:37:45.599Z'
> new Date(timestamp * 1000).toJSON()
'2021-03-06T21:19:59.426Z'
```